# jQuery .delay does not delay

Tags: jquery, delay

How can I set the html of an element, wait 2 seconds, then set the html to something else?

Example: `$("div").html("clicked").delay(2000).html("2 seconds have passed");`

What happens: the div gets "2 seconds have passed" off the bat, instead of saying "clicked" for 2 seconds, then displaying "2 seconds have passed".

Do I need to do something like, `.delay(2000, function() { $("div").html("2 seconds have passed"); })`?

Live example here: http://jsbin.com/UfaYusU/1/edit

Thanks!

Comment: you need to put it in queue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.delay is used to delay animations in a queue, not halt execution.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.delay()` by default only works with animating functions, you can use `.promise()` method:

```
$("div").html("clicked").delay(2000).promise().done(function() {
    $(this).html("2 seconds have passed");
});
```

Comment: " only works with animating functions," not really as far as i know. Works for everything put in queue

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, technically that's correct, I meant _by default_.

Comment: I've never think about using .promise() in this case, nice one even now multiple clicks in a row seems to break it  http://jsfiddle.net/fsvFj/

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually it doesn't break, since several promise objects are created, it waits when all of them are done, for example 5 clicks, 10 seconds,  I wouldn't create a promise object in this case, since it adds overhead but it's very useful in some cases.

Comment: That's make sense! Thx for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` if you want to run some code after a delay...

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  $("div").html("clicked");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").html("2 seconds have passed");
  }, 2000);
});
```

[Here's an updated version of your jsbin...](http://jsbin.com/UfaYusU/5/)